# Laravel 5.3/5.4 Mailgun Issue on Production Server

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, mailgun

I'm writing an app to generate & email PDF Invoices using Laravel 5.3 and using mailgun driver to send email. Everything works fine on my localhost, but when I put this online I got Error 500 Internal Server Error. When I increased execution time, I got cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).
What can be the cause? and how to rectify.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

> Controller Method

```
public function getEmailInvoice($number)
{
    try{
        $invoice = Invoice::whereNumber($number)->firstOrFail();
        Mail::to($invoice->account->emailAddresses->pluck('address')->toArray())
            ->queue(new SendInvoice($invoice));
        return back();
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

> build method from SendInvoice class:

```
public function build()
{
    $pdf = new PDFInvoice($this->invoice);

    return $this->from('fromEmailAddress', 'FromName')
        ->subject("Esto Internet Invoice for " . $this->invoice->date->format('F-Y'))
        ->subject("Esto Internet Invoice for " . $this->invoice->date->format('F-Y'))
        ->replyTo('replyToEmailAddress')
        ->view('admin.email.invoice')
        ->attachData($pdf->stream(), "{$this->invoice->account->username}-{$this->invoice->number}.pdf")
        ;
}
```

PDFInvoice extends FPDF library class, & following is the stream method from PDFInvoice:

```
public function stream()
{
    $this->_makeInvoice();
    return $this->Output('S');
}
```

Comment: 'What can be the cause?' hundreds of possibilities unless you provide more details & code

Comment: @hassan updated my question with code, what details you would like me to share?